# What simple thing is preventing Angular Datepicker from working?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm using the Angular Datepicker component for a form group - but with the datepicker implemented, the form doesn't load. When I remove the datepicker the form loads.

I've followed the documentation here https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview
I've searched for open issues that describe what I'm seeing and have not found any issues or stack overflow questions that match my issue.

I have a form within a stepper like this:

```
        <mat-step [stepControl]="projectOnboardingFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="projectOnboardingFormGroup" class="form">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Project Details</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input formControlName="projectNameOnboardingFormCtrl" matInput
                       placeholder="New Project" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input formControlName="projectTargetStartDateOnboardingFormCtrl" matInput
                       [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Target Start">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input formControlName="projectTargetFinishDateOnboardingFormCtrl" matInput
                       placeholder="Target Finish">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input formControlName="projectBusinessOwnerOnboardingFormCtrl" matInput
                       placeholder="Business Owner">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="full-width">
                <input formControlName="projectAdditionalNotesOnboardingFormCtrl" matInput
                       placeholder="Additional Notes">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button (click)="submitProjectOnboarding()" mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
```

When I try to load the form in Firefox, the page does not load and I get the following error:

[image: firefox_error]

The documentation says gives the following example:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And also says to add MatDatepickerModule to the relevant module, which I have done:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: OnboardingPage
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        SharedComponentsModule,
        MaterialModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatDatepickerModule
    ],
    declarations: [OnboardingPage]
})
export class OnboardingPageModule {
}
```

The only difference between this sample code and my own code is the presence of a form control name:

```
formControlName="projectTargetStartDateOnboardingFormCtrl"
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:
@Spierala - here is the definition for the project form controller, I've created them on init, project is the last one there. Also I've removed the form control and the datepicker still does not work, and the page doesn't load :(

@Mustafa - does the ngOnInit() code what you were wanting to see?

```
userOnboardingFormGroup: FormGroup;
companyOnboardingFormGroup: FormGroup;
teamOnboardingFormGroup: FormGroup;
projectOnboardingFormGroup: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.userOnboardingFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        userFirstNameOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
        userLastNameOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
        userEmailOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.userOnboardingFormGroup.setValue({
        userFirstNameOnboardingFormCtrl: this.user.firstName,
        userLastNameOnboardingFormCtrl: this.user.lastName,
        userEmailOnboardingFormCtrl: this.user.email
    });

    this.companyOnboardingFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        companyNameOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
        companyprimaryContactEmailAddressOnboardingFormCtrl: ['']
    });

    this.teamOnboardingFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        teamNameOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
        teamprimaryContactEmailAddressOnboardingFormCtrl: ['']
    });

    this.projectOnboardingFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        projectNameOnboardingFormCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    });
}
```

Comment: If you remove `formControlName="projectTargetStartDateOnboardingFormCtrl"` then it still does not work? Can you show the definition of `projectOnboardingFormGroup` in the component class ?

Comment: Can you share your ts code

Comment: I've updated the post with both of your questions, thanks!